# Simple constant select on primary key in small MEMORY table very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, memory-table

I have a MEMORY table with about 650 rows, 5 MB data length, 60 kB index length (so it's pretty small). It has one SMALLINT primary (hash) key, and about 90 other columns (ints, varchars, datetimes, no blobs or texts). (EDIT: there's also a hash key on a BIGINT column.)

I'm running this query (from PHP) quite often (about 10 times per second):

> select * from userek where id={CONST_ID} and kitiltva=0 and
>   kitiltva_meddig<"{CONST_DATETIME}" and inaktiv=0

Note: `id` is the primary key. I need the `*` because the result is used in a lot of different places, and basically all columns are used here or there.

**My problem** is: the query gets abnormally slow on a regular basis. About `0.5s` on average, `8s` max. Most of the times it's very fast: `75%` of runs faster than `3ms`, `85%` faster than the average. But `15%` it's slower than average, `13%` slower than `1s`. So it's got a long tail.

And I have absolutely no idea what might cause it. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: No other indexes on the table, except for the PK ?

Comment: Oh, there's another hash index on a BIGINT column. That's it.

Comment: A BTREE index on `(id,kitiltva,inaktiv,kitiltva_meddig)` would be the most appropriate for this query. But I haven't worked with MEMORY tables, so someone with more experince may advice if this (adding an index) would be appropriate to do in this case.

Comment: Or if there are other more plausible issues with memory tables.

Comment: EXPLAIN shows that the query is using the primary index with const, which is as far as I know the fastest possible solution. But you gave me an idea: I will try to get the other conditions out of the query (and into PHP), and we will see...

Comment: Oh, you mean that the `id` is the Primary Key? No idea, then.

Comment: One question: Is the query slow when it finds a row (that fulfills the conditions) or when it doesn't? Or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough then. Yes, `id` is the primary key.


I tried getting out the other conditions (so now the select is just `where id=const` but it's the same result.


I think the size of the result (one or no row) is irrelavant because in about 100% of the cases there is one row. But I'll check that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but at least I have an answer. I try to write it in a such a way that's helpful for others.

Since it's a MEMORY table, I excluded I/O problems.

Next, the query is a simple (const) select by the primary key, so it cannot be an indexing problem either.

The next guess was locking. There are/were some very slow selects in my application on this table. And it can be a problem: slow selects delay updates that delay other selects, so in the end this very simple and fast select can be delayed.

I checked the `slow query log` and found two frequent and slow selects that were using this particular table (and others as well). The cause was a badly formed join on a case:

```
A left join B on case
when A.x=1 then B.id=A.id2
when A.x=2 then B.id=A.id3
else B.id=0
end
```

instead of

```
A left join B on B.id = case
when A.x=1 then A.id2
when A.x=2 then A.id3
else 0
end
```

Both give the same result, but the latter can use an index of `B.id`, the former cannot.

Once I corrected these queries the performance of the *original* query was greatly enhanced: `5ms` instead of `500ms` on average. And `98%` faster than average.

The moral:

- use `slow query log`, analyse it, and improve slow queries
- if you encounter inexplicable slow-downs, always check for "crossing" queries that slow down your query by locking the same table

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question as it may help others in the future. It's also fine and helpful to mark this as the "accepted answer" by clicking the checkmark next to it. This alerts others right away to the fact that this answer worked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was not sure about accepting my own answer... I got the message "You can accept your own answer in 2 days", so I'll wait a bit...